# CodenameOne - Layered Layout import not working

Tags: layout, import, codenameone

According to the docu of LayeredLayout here ([JavaDoc)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/layouts/LayeredLayout.html), there is an inset method that can be used for relative positioning. I created a bare pones CN1 project and added this piece, also from the docu:

```
        Container cnt = new Container(new LayeredLayout());
        LayeredLayout ll = (LayeredLayout)cnt.getLayout();
        TextField searchField = new TextField();
        Button btn = new Button("Search");
        cnt.add(searchField).add(btn);
        ll
          .setInsets(searchField, "1mm auto auto auto")
          .setInsets(btn, "0 auto auto 0")
          .setReferenceComponentLeft(btn, searchField, 1f)
          .setReferenceComponentTop(btn, searchField, 0);
```

However, I am getting an error that the `setInset` Method is not found. Looking at the source of LayeredLayout class reveals that it indeed does not have this method.

`The method setInsets(TextField, String) is undefined for the type LayeredLayout`

I just updated CN1 lib to the latest version as of today.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest updating your plugin.

In `Codename One Settings` select `Basic` and click `Update Client Libs`.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Why is that necessary though? After updating the eclipse plugin for CN1, one should assume that the client libs are updated as well.
Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: They are but if you created the project before updating they won't be